# WAR file being deployed on TomEE - first time deployed not as expected, subsequent restarts result in ClassNotFoundExceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I've successfully deployed a war file that I exported using Eclipse to a local instance of a TomEE server, but when trying to do exactly the same thing with the war file on another server, I get the following output to the console:

```
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:47 PM org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor extract
INFO: Extracting jar: C:\Apache TomEE\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2\webapps\MyWar.war
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:47 PM org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor extract
INFO: Extracted path: C:\Apache TomEE\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2\webapps\MyWar 
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.ee6.MyFacesContainerInitializer onSt
artup
INFO: Added FacesServlet with mappings=[/faces/*, *.jsf, *.faces]
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEMyFacesContainerInitializ
er addListener
INFO: Installing <listener>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListen
er</listener>
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProv
ider getStandardFacesConfig
INFO: Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProv
ider getClassloaderFacesConfig
INFO: Reading config : jar:file:/C:/Apache%20TomEE/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2/lib
/openwebbeans-el22-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProv
ider getClassloaderFacesConfig
INFO: Reading config : jar:file:/C:/Apache%20TomEE/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2/lib
/openwebbeans-jsf-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
INFO: Artifact 'myfaces-api' was found in version '2.1.13' from path 'file:/C:/A
pache%20TomEE/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.13.jar'
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
INFO: Artifact 'myfaces-impl' was found in version '2.1.13' from path 'file:/C:/
Apache%20TomEE/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2/lib/myfaces-impl-2.1.13.jar'
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl getProje
ctStage
INFO: Couldn't discover the current project stage, using Production
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator handleSeria
lFactory
INFO: Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.
DefaultSerialFactory
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecyclePr
oviderFactory getLifecycleProvider
INFO: Using LifecycleProvider org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7Annota
tionLifecycleProvider
Jul 30, 2014 12:50:48 PM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer init
Faces
INFO: ServletContext initialized.
```

... the EJBs that are contained within the WAR are not initialised, and nothing happens.

Upon server restart, I get `ClassNotFoundException`s for all of the classes contained within my WAR (and now within WEB-INF/classes once exploded)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Guess it comes from the space, try in another folder with space maybe.